# Are sets of rational sequences open, or closed in $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

Are sets of rational sequences open, or closed in $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$?

I think that any subset of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$, since:

- Any subset is closed (it contains all its limit points)
- A complement of any subset is also closed

So are the subsets all clopen?

Disclaimer: $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ is the space of all rational sequences, endowed with product topology.

Comment: No, of course not. Think! $\Bbb Q$ is already not a space in which every subset is open or closed. So how could it be true for an infinite product of them (which only has bigger open subsets, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not true. For example $\{(0,0,..,)\}$ is not open. If it were open then there would be a finite number of intervals  $I_1,I_2,...,I_n$ around $0$  such that $x_1 \in I_1,x_2 \in I_2,..,x_n \in I_n$ implies $(x_1,x_2,..) \in \{(0,0,...)\}$ which is obviousy false.